# How rabbimq-server start with the custom rabbitmq.config and rabbmit-env.conf

Tags: rabbitmq

I installed rabbmitmq-server with binary .tar.gz, then i create rabbitmq-env.conf and rabbitmq.config.

In rabbitmq-env.conf i set

```
LOG_BASE=/var/log/rabbitmq
```

but when i start rabbitmq-server

```
vagrant@jinming:/usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4$ sudo rabbitmq-server

          RabbitMQ 3.5.4. Copyright (C) 2007-2015 Pivotal Software,       Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/sbin/../var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@jinming.log
  ######  ##        /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/sbin/../var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@jinming-sasl.log
```

The rabbitmq-server log not in /var/log/rabbitmq, it start not as i want. How to configure and how to start the server.

Comment: The log is still in $RABBITMQ_HOME/var/log/rabbitmq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install on Generic Unix,

```
$RABBITMQ_HOME/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf.
$RABBITMQ_HOME/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config.
```

are the default path of configuration. If you want to change this, find the line

```
SYS_PREFIX=${RABBITMQ_HOME}
```

in sbin/rabbitmq-defaults script and change this line to:

```
SYS_PREFIX=
```

Comment: Why not set RABBITMQ_HOME to something else insted of modifying the `rabbitmq-defaults` script?

Comment: I think set RABBITMQ_HOME work also, but i don't have a try, official site recommends my way.